# Terminology for a reversed graph (y, x)

Tags: terminology

In general if some terminology exists for an object, the complementary object is called the co-object (assuming it exists).

For the purpose of my research it is very useful to define graphs in reversed order, that is, {(y, x) such that y = f(x)}. I simply referred to them as graphs until now, but the time has come to name them something better! (As much as I would like to, I can't call them "graphs" because they're literally not graphs. I also feel that cograph isn't quite correct although I like the ring of it.)

Thank you

Comment: How about "antigraphs"?

Comment: How do you define graph?

Comment: Hm I guess antigraph works, but I want to capture the idea of "reflecting" - maybe I'll do some google translating from english to latin haha.
As for graphs, they're {(x, y) : y = f(x)}.

Comment: How about what they are normally called, reflections? In particular, these are reflections about the line $y=x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I called it a "contragraph" because contra is the usual prefix for reversing something. $\Gamma(f)$ is the usual notation in my field for denoting the graph, so I used \reflectbox{\Gamma}(f) for the contragraph.